# What is the meaning of "The wise, for care, on exercise depend, ..."?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> The wise, for care, on exercise depend, God never made his work for man to mend.

It's a quotation of Dryden made by [this essay](http://grammar.about.com/od/classicessays/a/Exercise-By-A-Bronson-Alcott.htm).

Another version is from [wikiquote: John Dryden](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/John_Dryden), where *for care* is actually *for cure*.

> The wise, for cure, on exercise depend; God never made his work for man to mend.

It's saying men should exercise, but what is the meaning and purpose of *for cure* or *for care*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original says *for cure*, not *for care*. Two simple [Google](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=%22The%20wise%20for%20cure%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) [searches](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=%22The%20wise%20for%20care%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) will verify that.

The maxim itself is saying the men should exercise **as a means of attaining better health**, as opposed using to man-made medicines. It today's world, he might rephrase it to something like:

> The wise, for weight control, on exercise depend; God never made our waistlines for diet pills to mend.

I suppose he's saying that it's best to try exercise first; I'm not sure he's going so far as to say, "Never trust doctors about anything at all," but I'd have to do more research into his world views to say for sure.  If I was feeling under the weather, though, it sounds like he'd recommend a brisk walk and some fresh air before advising that I reach for the aspirin bottle.

Comment: You're welcome – although you might want to wait half a day or so before accepting an answer. Accepting an answer prematurely might deter other users from leaving other answers that could enhance or improve the discussion. Just a thought.

Comment: Ok, I'll wait then.